# How to remove "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" header only in specific usercontrol ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, http-headers

I need implement "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" http header in the website. However, in a specific usercontrol .ascx can't been implemented.

How to remove "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" header only in specific usercontrol ascx?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you implementing it? Can you show it to us?

Comment: In te web.config